# Rust how to convert Vec<f32> to Vec<[f32; 3]> - Given format is Float32 but expected Float32x3

Tags: rust, vector, iterator, bevy

In bevy(0.10) I am discovering the transvoxel module, and in its current state* won't let the `bevy_mesh` feature to be enabled because of some dependency problems; So I'm manually converting its output to a `bevy::Mesh`.

One of the tasks this requires is to convert from a Vec to Vec<[f32; 3]>, so that each (xyz) coordinate is in one place.

Since I'm new to Rust I was wondering if there are best practices to achieve this.

So far what I tried is the following:

```
let mut pos2: Vec<[f32; 3]> = Vec::new(); // A vector to contain VertexFormat::Float32x3
let i = 0; 
extracted_mesh.positions.into_iter().map(|u|{
    if i % 3 == 0 {
        pos2.push([0.,0.,0.]);
}
    if let Some(pos3) = pos2.last_mut() {pos3[i % 3] = u};
});
```

Which I would say is really ugly, but seems to do the job.
I'm interested in if there's a `map(...).collect()` way to do this, as this itself produces a warning:

```
warning: src/meshgen.rs:28: unused `std::iter::Map` that must be used
note: src/meshgen.rs:28: iterators are lazy and do nothing unless consumed
```

*as of 2023. March

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `positions` is a `Vec` or something along those lines there is [`slice::chunks`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.chunks) and [`slice::chunks_exact`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.chunks_exact), although they yield slices so you need to `try_into` them into fixed-size arrays:

```
v.chunks(3).map(|c| <[_;3]>::try_from(c).unwrap()).collect::<Vec<_>>()
```

If you can swing it itertools has the even better [`Itertools::tuples`](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.tuples), which collects items into the a tuple the exact size you want, you just need to move them over to an array, with no panics to be seen:

```
v.into_iter().tuples().map(|(a, b, c)| [a, b, c]).collect::<Vec<_>>()
```

Comment: Thanks for the awesome answer! Might I ask what does "swinging it" mean?

Comment: do it / manage it / allow it. There might be environment where itertools is not available, and there are people who try to limit dependencies unless absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 2):

In case the vectors you want to convert are large and you have to avoid copying of the data you can do so by transforming the vector:

```rust
use std::mem::ManuallyDrop;
pub fn to_arrays<const N: usize, T>(mut v: Vec<T>) -> Vec<[T; N]> {
    assert_eq!(v.len() % N, 0, "length not divisible by {N}");
    if v.capacity() % N != 0 {
        v.shrink_to_fit();
        assert_eq!(v.capacity() % N, 0, "capacity not divisible by {N} and we could not shrink to make it so");
    }
    let mut v = ManuallyDrop::new(v);
    let (ptr, len, cap) = (v.as_mut_ptr(), v.len(), v.capacity());
    // SAFETY:
    // * Global allocator is given `Vec<T> == Vec<T, Global>`
    // * an array has the same alingment as it's items
    // * len / N arrays of [T; N] have been initialized because len items have been initialized before
    // * capacity is divisible by N so the allocation is the same sisze
    unsafe { Vec::from_raw_parts(ptr.cast(), len / N, cap / N) }
}
```

Comment: That's a very clever trick. It took me some time to agree that it's sound, but after carefully reading the documentation I understand that it really is. One thing I would change through is  that I wouldn't use `ManuallyDrop`, but simply called `Vector::into_raw_parts`. Anyway great solution. Thanks!

Comment: But on the other hand having capacity being a multiple of `N` is not something we could guarantee in any way (without writing our own `Vec` at least), and calling `shrink_to_fit` would have to reallocate the whole vector anyway, making effectively the same `memcopy` as we would do doing it ourselves.

Comment: @AleksanderKrauze I'd use `into_raw_parts` too if it wasn't unstable, and `shrink_to_fit` might be able to just free from the end but there's really no other option if if the `capacity` not divisible by `N`

Comment: I didn't realize that into raw parts was unstable. Thanks for teaching me another thing today! Also doesn't global allocator require that memory passed to `dealoc` is *whole* of memory allocated with `alloc`? I thought that it's impossible to fee only a part of memory.

Comment: It does and you're right it is currently implemented by [allocating new space, copy, deallocating old space](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/alloc/global.rs.html#261-276) but there is really nothing preventing an allocators `realloc` from changing the size of an existing allocation without copying.